# Unix: Strings beginning and ending with certain characters and writing them in a text doc

Tags: grep

So basically, the task is to count the number of students from who (command in putty) which have a student ID starting with 15 or 16 and ending with even number are currently logged into the machine, and write the output in the file sample.txt.

I've tried this command and it doesn't seem to work...

```
grep '^15\|16.*[02468]' | who | wc -l > sample.txt
```

Example:

155053

165054

175055

155056

Num of lines: 2

Any ideas?

Comment: Why your attempt didn't work (it generates too many hits): You are not using parentheses anywhere, so the alternation (the "or" choice) is between `^15` and `16.*[02468]`. So, you will select all strings that begin with 15 (no matter what follows that), and also all strings that have 16 **anywhere** in the string, and then end in an even digit. (Which digit must be different from the `6` in the `16` match, though). You want the "begin" anchor to apply to everything, and also `.*[02468]` to apply to everything; so you need `15\|16` in parentheses.

Comment: But then, of course, the `1` is common to both choices, so you can rewrite as `^1\(5\|6\).*[02468]$`. And finally, `\(5\|6\)` is the same as `[56]` (choosing a single character from the list).

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
grep '^1[56].*[02468]$'
```

See the [grep demo online](https://ideone.com/PBHAmp).

**Detais**

- `^` - start of string
- `1` - `1`
- `[56]` - `5` or `6`
- `.*` - ant 0+ chars (replace with `[0-9]*` if you want to make sure pnly digit-only strings are matched)
- `[02468]` - `0`, `2`, `4`, `6`, `8`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, putty doesn't give me access to a new command. Usually it would do [185053@os ~] and then a new command but it doesn't now. I think it has something to do with the `who` command

Comment: it says `-bash: cannot create temp file for here document: No space left on device 0` when i enter it

Comment: @BojanPetkovski `who` output is in `ubuntu   pts/0        2020-05-18 08:02 (12.34.56.789)` - don't you want to do something like `who | grep '....'`? But what is the expected output then?